# Eclipse : The import org.apache cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

I have a problem to compile a project with import of apache.

Here is the error :

[image]

And here is my import :

[image]

Comment: i think you must extract `log4j-1.2.17.zip` then import the jar file.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you have included `log4j-1.2.17.zip` in your build Path. You need to extract this zip file and get the `log4j-1.2.17.jar` and add that to your class path. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a POM file to handle dependencies. Therefore adding jar files to class path manually was not an option.

After doing a lot of research, found out that the java project was not a maven project.
To mavenize project in eclipse the following was done as noted [here](https://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/):

1. right click on Java Project
2. click Configure and select "Convert to Maven Project"

This added maven dependancies automatically to the project and the error "The import org.apache cannot be resolved" went away.